# Unity: Need help how to double click detection in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouseevent

I wanna create mouse click that detect single click, hold click, and double click.
When I do single click, the character will faster (moveSpeed = 15), when I hold click and double click there is no action, the character still constant with it speed (moveSpeed = 3).

Here is my code:

```
private float t0, moveSpeed;
private bool longClick, shortClick;

void Start () 
{ t0 = 0f; longClick = false; shortClick = false; }


void update()
{
    // how to add the code for detect double click and where I write it?

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        t0 = 0; t0 += Time.deltaTime;
        longClick = false;  shortClick = false;
        moveSpeed = 0;
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {         
        t0 += Time.deltaTime;
        if (t0 < 0.2)
        { moveSpeed = 15;longClick = false; shortClick = true; } // this is single click!
        if (t0 > 0.2)
        { moveSpeed = 3; longClick = true; shortClick = false; } // this is hold click!
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))     
    {
         if (longClick == true)
         {    moveSpeed = 3;   }
         else if (shortClick = true)
         {    moveSpeed = 3;   }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried googling? - See the second answer here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/331545/double-click-mouse-detection-.html

In C#:

```
private float lastClickTime;

public float catchTime = 0.25f;

void Update ()
{

    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        if(Time.time - lastClickTime < catchTime)
        {
            //double click
            print("Double click");
        }
        else
        {
            //normal click
        }
        lastClickTime = Time.time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I replied here: http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1133702/view.html

Basically: create a new class with the doubleClicked checker inside. Then use it in an if clause.

```
class DoubleClickListener  {
  bool firstClick = false;
  float runningTimerSecond;

  float delay = 0.25F;

  public DoubleClickListener() { }

  public DoubleClickListener(float delay) {
    this.delay = delay;
  }

  public bool isDoubleClicked() {
    // If the time is too long we reset first click variable
    if (firstClick && (Time.time - runningTimerSecond) > delay) {
      firstClick = false;
    }

    if (!firstClick) {
      firstClick = true;
      runningTimerSecond = Time.time;
    } else {
      firstClick = false;
      return true;
    } 

    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DoubleClickBehaviorBase is a base class that will take care of double click for you.
You inherit from DoubleClickBehaviorBase instead of MonoBehavior
All you need to do is override OnDoubleClickOverride in your class.
I've also included a MonoBehaviourExtension that makes it easier to call and 
implement StartCoroutine:

```
namespace DoubleClick
{
    public static class MonoBehaviourExtension
    {
        public static void StartCoroutine(this MonoBehaviour mb, params Action[] funcs)
        { 
            mb.StartCoroutine(CoroutineRunnerSimple(funcs));
        }
        private static System.Collections.IEnumerator CoroutineRunnerSimple(Action[] funcs)
        {
            foreach (var func in funcs)
            {
                if (func != null)
                    func();

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(.01f);
            }
        }
    }



    abstract public class DoubleClickBehaviorBase : MonoBehaviour
    {
        float _DoubleClickTimer = 0.0f;
        float _DoubleClickDelay = 0.5f;
        bool _WasClicked = false;

        // Update is called once per frame
        protected virtual void Update()
        {
            // this starts timing when a click occurs 
            //
            if (this._WasClicked == true)
            {
                this._DoubleClickTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            }

            // this must be in update because it expires based on time and not clicks
            //
            if (this._DoubleClickTimer > this._DoubleClickDelay)
            {
                this._WasClicked = false;
                this._DoubleClickTimer = 0.0f;

            }
        }
        protected virtual void OnMouseDoubleClick()
        {
        }

        protected virtual void OnMouseDown()
        {
            if (this._WasClicked == false && this._DoubleClickTimer < _DoubleClickDelay)
            {
                this._WasClicked = true;
            }
            else if (this._WasClicked == true && 
                     this._DoubleClickTimer < this._DoubleClickDelay)
            {
                this.StartCoroutine(() => this.OnMouseDoubleClick());
            }
        }
    }
}
```